# Cannot find module '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs'

Tags: typescript

I added the fingerprints config in `package.json` like this(already installed using command `yarn add @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs`):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.178",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "npm": "^8.4.1"
  },
```

then when I import the lib in project using this code:

```
import FingerprintJS from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs';
```

shows error info:

```
'FingerprintJS' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Cannot find module '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?ts(2792)
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you installed first after you adding the package? try typing `npm i`

Comment: check your node modules for the package